# Why the image of a minimal surface $S$ ($\kappa(S)=1$) defined by a linear system $|M|$ is a curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm reading the proof of Proposition IX.2 in Beauville's "Complex algebraic surfaces", and I do not understand a part of it:

Suppose we have a minimal surface $S$ of Kodaira dimension $\kappa(S)=1$. Then we have that $K_S^2=0$, so we can apply Lemma IX.1 and get that we can write $$rK_S\sim Z+M$$ where $Z$ is the fixed part of the system $|rK_S|$ and $M$ is the mobile part which satisfies $M^2=K_S\cdot M=0$. Then $|M|$ defines a morphism to $\mathbb{P}^N$ for some $N$ the image of which is a curve.

I do not understand how does it follow that the image of this morphism is a curve? Is this some quality of $|M|$ being a mobile part?

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: The point is (roughly) that 1) the image of $|rK_S|$ is a curve for $r >>1$, and 2) subtracting the fixed part of a linear system will not change the number of sections or the extent to which they separate points.

Comment: I see, thank you!:)